Basic Super Copy bones will not generate controls, only appear on generated rig hidden under ORG/DEF. (Rigify)

I am attempting to animate ears for my model via a basic super copy. I was able to create hair and tail bones using the tail samples provided, and they all connected find. However, when attempting to do the exact same thing to create these Super Copy Bones, they fail to generate anything except hidden bones on the final rig.
I created a sample basic super copy, moved it in to place, parented it to the same bone as the hair, spine.006, symmetrized it with its new name as Cat Ear.L, and double checked in pose mode that both bones had the appropriate rig type. I am unsure what I may have done wrong since everything else is generating as it should.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
